# "Unwanted events happened"

Tags: passive-voice, intransitive-verbs

"Unwanted events happened" couldn't be an example for passive because there's no **objective** in the sentence, it's just like this example, "the child cried", because "happen" is an **intransitive** verb.

https://www.duolingo.com/comment/9213318

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as linguists and grammarians are concerned, you are correct that "Unwanted events happened" is not in the passive voice. (Your explanation is not quite right, however, since true passive-voice verbs don't require the objective case, either: we say "I was robbed", not *"Me was robbed". And anyway, the distinction between the subjective and objective cases only applies to pronouns; "unwanted events" would have the same form either way.)

However, many English speakers have only an imprecise understanding of "passive voice", and think that "passive" describes a sentence that conceals or de-emphasizes the agent. (They have probably misgeneralized from examples like ["Mistakes were made"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mistakes_were_made), where the passive voice is used for that purpose.) So I think it's fair to say that the term "passive" now has two loosely-related meanings: a technical sense relating to syntax, and a non-technical sense relating to semantics and pragmatics.

Answer (score 0):

"happened" is no passive. The passive would be "was happened" or "to be happened". (Both passive forms make no sense.) For passive you need a form of to be + past participle.